# Adding Stop and Reset buttons to NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, reset

I have created a NSTimer that simply times minutes and I am wishing to add a stop and reset button to it. So far my code looks like this:

```
@implementation TimeController

int timeTick = 0;


NSTimer *timer;   

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    labelTime.text = @"0";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:(self) selector:(@selector(tick)) userInfo:(nil) repeats:(YES)];
}

-(void)tick{
    timeTick++;
    NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    labelTime.text = timeString;



}


@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `timeTick` and `timer` are actually globals which is probably not what you intended. You should probably declare them as instance variables. This will allow you to have multiple instances of your `TimeController` and have them all count independently.

Then your code may look something like this

```
@interface TimeController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger  minutes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer   *timer;

@end

@implementation TimeController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self updateMinuteLabel];
}

- (IBAction)startTimer
{
  [self.timer invalidate];
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 
                                                target:self 
                                              selector:@selector(tick) 
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)stopTimer
{
  [self.timer invalidate];
}

- (IBAction)resetTimer
{
  self.minutes = 0;
  [self updateMinuteLabel];
}

- (void)tick
{
  self.minutes += 1;
  [self updateMinuteLabel];
}

- (void)updateMinuteLabel
{
  self.minuteLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.minutes];
}

@end
```

Comment: I am saving the timeTick variable to Core Data. Does this revision affect that?

Comment: Where exactly are you doing that? The data is available it's up to you to take `self.timer` and save it to core data at the right time

Comment: I have a separate view controller with a separate class to save the data. How could I save the data from the separate class? Could I keep the variables as global?

Comment: Declare the ovary in the header and then it will be publicly accessible through accessors. You should avoid globals where possible

Comment: Ok. Could you please show what it would look like to access it from another class?

Comment: `NSInteger minutes = timeControllerInstance.minutes`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help so far! Where would I place this code?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I couldn't really say. When you want to save the minutes you need to ask this controller for the value of its minutes property then update your core data model and save